# Android Text to Speech non google engine

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my android app I have a TTS using Google engine.

Have something like this:

```
tts=new TextToSpeech(MyClass.this, status -> {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
       tts.setLanguage(locale);
       tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

                if (utteranceId.equals("***")) {

                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    Button view2 = findViewById(R.id.speech);
                    view2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.play, 0, 0, 0);
                });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Basically I am using 2 languages, slovak and english. Both are working fine with Google TTS.

The problem is, Samsung devices have their own TTS engine set by default and therefore the app text to speech works not on those devices.

After the users changes their device settings to use Google TTS, then it is working.

But is there a way, that my code will support both TTS engines?

I found out that there might work something like this:

```
TextToSpeech(Context context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener, String engine)
```

e.g. using `com.google.android.tts` as the engine parameter.

However in my code I have that like `new TextToSpeech(MyClass.this, status -> {`... and it doesn't accept engine as a 3rd parameter, and still I don't know how to detect when Samsung engine is needed and switch engines accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

worth trying forcing TTS engine by passing this third param, so exchange very last line in posted snippet

```
});
```

to

```
}, "com.google.android.tts");
```

there are also two useful methods for you: [`getDefaultEngine()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#getDefaultEngine()) and [`getEngines()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#getEngines()). just create at start some dummy `new TextToSpeech` with two params (empty listener) and check what possibilites you have.

also [`getAvailableLanguages()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#getAvailableLanguages()) and [`isLanguageAvailable(Locale loc)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#isLanguageAvailable(java.util.Locale)) may be useful when Google engine isn't present, but default one still may support your desired langs

Comment: seems last time I put it on the wrong place, now the 3rd parameter is accepted. But is it forcing to use Google TTS now? What if the Samsung device has Samsung TTS set up, then how can it force to use Google TTS? Your suggestion with getDefaultEngine() seems good, I will take a look, I think it will get the device's default engine and I can replace the 3rd parameter with that, if I am not wrong

Comment: according to doc this third param enforce desired TTS intead of default, BUT... what happens when `getEngines()` won't return Googles implementation? you have to write some code for checking is your desired engine present on device and if it can speak in desired language. if not you may still use any other engine with checking language availability

Comment: I see, that's why I better don't force google TTS, so then getDefaultEngine() should work I hope. If the default engine is Samsung, then it should work with that, if the default is Google, then use Google. Then EN and SK language should be no problem for both engines

Comment: note that every time you create `new TextToSpeech(...)` then list returned by this object and `getAvailableLanguages()` method may be different... there is a chance that there will be no Google TTS at all, default would be ABC TTS engine, but without your lang support and also some secondary XYZ engine with desired support. imho you should create `new TextToSpeech(...)` (two param), get list of all engines, then create yet another `new TextToSpeech(...)` with forced engine (third param), then check if language is available